# Are Unit Tests with Google Test exported with project?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I've been studying Unit Testing with Google Test in C++.

If the purpose of Unit Testing is to ensure certain segments or objects of the code are working the way they are supposed to, I would assume it's not necessary to compile and export the unit testing code with the final project, right? It's not like the user will be using it anyway. It just seems like it makes the project size unnecessarily larger.

My main question is: will all the Unit Testing code be compiled and exported with the final project or will I have to manually delete all the Unit Tests before exporting it?

Is there a best (or common) practice for Unit Testing and exporting projects?

Comment: If your components under test follow the "open" principle, then all your tests can be external to the product, and therefore not included in the "installer", but may be included in SDK form if it's a library.  If the components follow the "closed" principle, then tests may have needed to be baked into the internals.  You'll have to decide how invasive those tests are and whether or not they need to be removed before production.  See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199090/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-modify-code-strictly-for-testing-purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're publishing a library, it's quite common to publish the unit tests. Imagine you're developing on Mac or Linux, for example, and someone wants to compile on Windows. Well, they should probably be able to run your tests to ensure they pass on a different environment. Or Android, or some microcontroller. Whatever.

Also, someone might decide to help you improve your project. They'll add a nifty-cool feature. It's nice if they can run your unit tests to make sure they don't break anything.

So yes, if you're publishing your project as source code, include the unit tests. If you're only publishing a compiled library, you can exclude them.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! I'm curious, for unit testing, I write them in the same file as the class objects I test. Is it best practice to put all the unit test code in one file? That way, I can exclude that file if I ever need to export the project without compiling the unit tests.

Comment: @Mathematician I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The trend seems to have a tests directory with all the automated tests, and those don't get compiled into anything you ship.

Answer (score 0):

Any tests are used for maintaining source code.

When you do some changes in source code, the you should run test to verify that: new functionality is working properly and old functionality is didn't got broken.
If test tails this is signal for developer that something has to be fixed.

So if your application or library is shipped as exactable there is o point to ship tests. Why? When you have only executable you can't modify code, so no point to run tests.

If you are publishing a library as open source then you test should be published too.

If you are publishing your library only as executable, source code of test can be form of documentation. If test are written properly they will document how API can be used in every possible way and as since test are a code (formal language) this form of documentation can't be misinterpret.

Shipping tests as executable has no seance at all.

I recommend to watch Uncle Bob (Robert C. Martin) talks, in most of them he explains what are test for and why they are important.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check it out.